# Is this theory equivalent to TG set theory?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is the following theory equivalent to [Tarski-Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory) set theory?

The language is first order logic with equality, and membership, with axiom schemata:

1. **Specification:** $\forall A \exists! x \, \forall y \, (y \in x \iff y \in A \land \phi )$
2. **Reflection:** $(\varphi \implies \exists \alpha: \operatorname {superinclusive}(V_\alpha) \land \varphi^{V_\alpha} )$

$\operatorname {superinclusive}(X) \equiv_{df} \forall Y \subseteq X \, (|Y|<|X| \implies Y \in X)$

$\varphi$ is a first order formula in the language of set theory + defined predicates and functions, that doesn't use the symbol $\alpha$. And $\varphi^X$ is the formula obtained by merely bounding all quantifiers in $\varphi$ by $\in X$. The formula $\phi$ (of specification) is any formula that doesn't have the symbol $x$ occurring free.

Comment: Surely you want to add extensionality, something to imply the existence of $V_\alpha$, etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, extensionality is a theorem here.

Comment: In the axiom schema of specification, $\text{FV}(\phi)$ is not allowed to contain $A$, right? Also, are you allowing $\phi$ to contain parameters?

Comment: @GregNisbet, are you asking if $\phi$ is allowed to contain $A$, or parameters? The answer is yes. $\phi$ is only shunned from containing $x$.

Comment: What sort of properties of $\alpha$ does $\textrm{superinclusive}(V_\alpha)$ imply? I believe it implies regularity of $\alpha$: assume towards contradiction that $\textrm{cof}\alpha<\alpha\land\textrm{superinclusive}(V_\alpha)$. Then taking some sequence $(\alpha_\xi)_{\xi<\textrm{cof}\alpha}$ cofinal in $\alpha$, construct the subset $Y=\{V_{\alpha_\xi}\mid\xi<\textrm{cof}\alpha\}\subseteq V_\alpha$, which by $\textrm{cof}\alpha<\alpha$ has cardinality strictly less than $\vert V_\alpha\vert$. But $Y$ contains members of $\alpha$-unbounded rank so it can't be contained in $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @C7X, hmm.., I think it also implies that $V_\alpha$ must be closed under powerset operator, since if not, then this would entail that $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, then $\{V_{\alpha-1}\}$ would be in $V_\alpha$ (by superinclusiveness), but $V_\alpha$ is the powerset of $V_{\alpha-1}$, a contradiction!

Comment: @C7X, it appears to me that superinclusiveness of $V_\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is uncountable means inaccessible $\alpha$, this would definitely establish the equivalence of TG set theory I suppose. But I need to examine the details.

Comment: OK from above $\alpha$ would be a regular strong limit cardinal and  so when uncountable it is inaccessible! This will prove all axioms of TG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theory proves ORD is $\Sigma_2$-Mahlo, that is, that every $\Sigma_2$-definable closed unbounded class contains an inaccessible cardinal. If $\phi$ is a $\Sigma_2$ formula that defines a closed unbounded class, we can apply the reflection schema to get an inaccessible cardinal $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha \vDash \text{the class defined by $\phi$ is closed and unbounded}$. Since $\phi$ is $\Sigma_2$ and $\alpha$ is inaccessible and thus a beth fixed point, $\phi$ is upward absolute from $V_\alpha$, so $\alpha$ is a limit of the class defined by $\phi$ and thus, since that class is closed, $\alpha$ is in that class.

For example, this proves that there are unboundedly many inaccessible limits of inaccessible cardinals, so this theory is stronger than Tarski-Grothendieck set theory. I don't know if this theory proves the full ORD is Mahlo schema.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer to this question. It only establishes proving that $\sf TG$ set theory is a fragment of this theory!

All axioms of $\sf ZF$ would follow from Specification + Reflection on stages $V_\alpha$ of the cumulative hierarchy. This is well known (D. Scott, [M. Potter 13.3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199270414)).

Superinclusiveness would prove both Choice, and Tarski's axiom.

Choice is proved because each superinclusive $V_\alpha$ would be in bijection with the set
$ON^{V_\alpha}$ of all von Neumann ordinals in it, since clearly $ON^{V_\alpha}$ is a cofinal subset of $V_\alpha$ (with respect to relation "strictly smaller rank"), and so it cannot be an element of $V_\alpha$, and so it must not be strictly smaller than $V_\alpha$ (superinclusiveness). Since every set is an element of some superinclusive stage, then it must be well-orderable after that bijection.

Tarski's axiom follows because every superinclusive $V_\alpha$ higher than $V_\omega$ would have $\alpha$ being strongly inaccessible, accordingly $V_\alpha$ would be a Grothendieck universe! To prove that, we see that $\alpha$ must be regular, since otherwise any strictly smaller cofinal subset of it would be an element of that stage (superinclusiveness) and thus rank-bounded within that stage, which cannot be! Also one can easily see that $V_\alpha$ must be closed on power set operator, since otherwise $\alpha$ would be a successor ordinal, and so the set $\{V_{\alpha-1}\}$ would be an element of $V_\alpha$ (superinclusiveness), which cannot be since all elements of $V_\alpha$ are *subsets* of $V_{\alpha-1}$. So every $\alpha$ for a superinclusive $V_\alpha$ is a regular strong limit cardinal, and when uncountable then it is inaccessible by definition.

Now, the other direction, that $\sf TG$ set theory can prove all axioms of this theory, is one I didn't reach to. And I suspect that it might not be the case. For I suspect that [$\sf Ack + limitation \ of \ size$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317658/what-is-the-strength-of-adding-limitation-of-size-and-a-simple-version-of-reflec) is a conservative extension of this theory, and so this would mean that this theory is equivalent with [ORD is mahlo](http://cantorsattic.info/ORD_is_Mahlo), and accordingly stronger than $\sf TG$ set theory.